# wxPython checkbox true or false

Tags: python, wxpython, append

So let's say that I have a checkbox in wxPython:

```
cb1 = wx.CheckBox(panelWX, label='TIME', pos=(20, 20))
cb1.SetValue(False)
```

Is there a simple way I could check to see whether it has changed to true?
Like this maybe?

```
if cb1.SetValue == True:
```

And from that point append something from the action of it being true?
Like so:

```
selectionSEM1.append('Time')
```

Comment: I don't care whether or not it becomes false again, just if it HAS become true at any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Events](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/events/).

```
def do_something(event):
    box = event.GetEventObject()
    setting = box.GetValue()
    if setting:
            selectionSEM1.append('Time')
    event.Skip()

cb1.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, do_something, cb1)
```

Comment: But then how could I get an event to append something into a list existing in the main method? As far as I can tell there is no way for me to put extra arguments into there.

Comment: @LukeG, how familiar are you with OOP? Any attributes of an object (whether or not they're declared in main) should be accessible by that object's methods. Without extra information in the question, its difficult to provide more specific help.

Answer (score 5):

you just need to use `GetValue()` method. look at this example from wxpython wiki:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# checkbox.py

import wx

class MyCheckBox(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(250, 170))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.cb = wx.CheckBox(panel, -1, 'Show Title', (10, 10))
        self.cb.SetValue(True)

        wx.EVT_CHECKBOX(self, self.cb.GetId(), self.ShowTitle)

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def ShowTitle(self, event):
        if self.cb.GetValue():#here you check if it is true or not
            self.SetTitle('checkbox.py')
        else: self.SetTitle('')


app = wx.App(0)
MyCheckBox(None, -1, 'checkbox.py')
app.MainLoop()
```